# Passing a Selector Through a Class Reference

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sorting, selector

I want to write a general array sorter that only takes two arguments: the array to be sorted and the class that holds an implementation of a comparator, where the class reference contains a class method to be used.

The method structure should look something like:

```
+(NSArray*) sortArray:(NSArray*)unsortedArray withClass:(Class)classReference{
    return [unsortedArray sortedArrayUsingSelector: @selector([classReference comparator])];
}
```

The basic idea will be to allow me to write a protocol to be used when sorting array by different data types and then pass the class and it's array to a Utility class where it can sort and return the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use blocks. For example, like this:

```
+(NSArray*) sortArray:(NSArray*)unsortedArray withClass:(Class)classReference{
     return [unsortedArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(id obj1, id obj2){
         return (NSComparisonResult)[classReference compare:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:obj1, obj2, nil]];
}];
```